# Why is my background image disappearing/flickering (bootstrap)?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am noticing an interesting problem with my site. I have a section that has a static background image and as you scroll there's a quote and button (eventually will link to a store) over the top of it. To my knowledge, it was working in the past, but yesterday I noticed after a few seconds the background image is gone, replaced with just a gray background. The image will flicker in and out a bit before permanently being replaced with the gray background.

Here is my HTML:

```
<section class="bar background-image-fixed-2 no-mb color-white text-center">
    <div class="dark-mask"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="icon icon-lg"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
                </div>
                <h3><em>"Herb is the healing of a nation" - Bob Marley</em></h3>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-black btn-lg">Get Some</a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.bar.background-image-fixed-2 {
  background-image: url('../img/fixed-background-2.jpg'); 
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

The image URL is correct because it initially loads for a couple of seconds. Originally, this was written short hand but some suggestions I've seen recommended doing the long form for the CSS. I split it out, but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

Actual look (incorrect):
[image: Actual]

Expected look (which I get for a few seconds before it changes automatically):

[image]

Edit:

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/69511/) (though it's missing some javascript so it'll look funny).

Comment: ONE LOVE, sorry for the spam comment. I'm trying to make a fiddle of your code btw.

Comment: Is it doing this on all browsers?

Comment: can you make an example with your code that reproduces the problem ? otherwise we cannot help you

Comment: Chrome and IE so far, yes. I can't add my entire HTML and CSS code because of character restrictions.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

please check your url is not proper loading :

```css
.bar.background-image-fixed-2 {
  background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490810277975-e64342ceecf0?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=88e69bf894f334456f8ae269752556e1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1650&q=80'); 
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">


<section class="bar background-image-fixed-2 no-mb color-white text-center">
    <div class="dark-mask"></div>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="icon icon-lg"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>
                </div>
                <h3 class="text-white"><em>"Herb is the healing of a nation" - Bob Marley</em></h3>
                <p class="text-center">
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-template-transparent-black btn-lg">Get Some</a>
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I used that URL, and I still got the same issue.